# lectura por teclado de una matricula de ocho caracteres, siendo obligatoria el primero una letra

Tags: java

```
public ExMatricula() {
    }
     ExMatricula(String s){
         super(s);
     }
     ExMatricula(int mal_formada){
         this();mal_formada=mal_formada;
     }
     public int DimeProblema(){
         return mal_formada;
     }
    private boolean UnaLetra(String matricula){
        return matricula.substring(0,1).matches("[A-Za-Z]");
    }

public void caracteres(String  matricula)throws ExPropia{
    try{
     if (matricula.length()!=8) {
        throw new ExMatricula(ExMatricula.mal_tamaño);
    }else{
         if (!UnaLetra(matricula)) {
             throw new ExMatricula(ExMatricula.mal_letra);
         }
     }
    }catch(ExMatricula e) { 

 switch (e.DimeProblema()) { 

 case ExMatricula.mal_tamaño: 
 System.out.println("Tamanio incorrecto"); 
 break; 
 case ExMatricula.mal_letra: 
 System.out.println("Letra inicial no incluida"); 
 break; 
 default: 
 System.out.println("Matricula correcta"); 
 break; 
              } 
}
}
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta carece de la informacion necesaria para que alguno de nosotros pueda ayudarte. Por favor consulta [como preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla.

Comment: ¿En qué falla tu código? ¿No crees que convendría que agregues una descripción en el cuerpo de la pregunta, más allá de lo que escribiste en el título? ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Además, para facilitar la lectura de alguien que quiera responderte, ¿no crees que sería más práctico indentar el código correctamente?

Comment: tienen razón, gracias...para la otra especificaré más, aunque ya lo pude solucionar, pero quiero practicar mucho para que más adelante pueda yo ayudar a personas así como yo en este momento